# Bluemix app - list whole activity log (events)

Tags: debugging, logging, ibm-cloud

I am currently debugging what happened with our app on Bluemix and would really like to list all entries from ACTIVITY LOG viewlet (since the "beginning of time" if possible) because of now it is full of the error message and no one can read what happened before. This is the error message.

**an instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within health check timeout**

I have already tried `cf events APP_NAME`, but it seems the result list is the same.

Please, how can I get longer list of previous app events?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve that information using CF API REST call. You can find the CF APIs documentation here:

- https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/197/events/list_all_events.html

In this specific case you could do a curl call in order to retrieve the latest 100 events:

> curl "https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/events?results-per-page=100" -X
>   GET -H "Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidWFhLWlkLTc5IiwiZW1haWwiOiJlbWFpbC01MEBzb21lZG9tYWluLmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjpbImNsb3VkX2NvbnRyb2xsZXIuYWRtaW4iXSwiYXVkIjpbImNsb3VkX2NvbnRyb2xsZXIiXSwiZXhwIjoxNDIyOTkwODY3fQ.rLrrVSCnC7eoiHwHgTLIWqFP4rf7XrINU9uedb1ikAI"

You can retrieve the Authorization header with:

```
cf oauth-token
```

after login to IBM Bluemix (cf login)

You can retrive events in a specific date using the **timestamp** parameter.

Comment: Thank you, Crescenzo, this is exactly what I needed to know! Appreciate your help.